# Two Phase commit-How to test

Tags: java, apache, jboss, 2phase-commit

We are trying to implement two phase commit on a Java/Jboss/Apache environment.

However we have difficulty understanding how we can test  that it actually works?
are there any gui tools that can help us test it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I can think of couple of scenarios

- unplug once of the resources participating in a 2PC. my favorite
- let one of the db operations fail with integrity constraint

The transaction should rollback.

Comment: ok... thanks.is anyone aware of any emulators/simulators out there

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider adding some hooks to your application to force a failure at each stage one by one; so you can check the expected outcome.

Or use unit testing if thats easier.